# Is this correct way to use loops or should it be in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

The `results` variable is coming from an API that have a arrays in arrays, etc.

I have made a `foreach` with `for` loops inside, which looks like this:

```
foreach (var s in results)
{
    var dataRowsCollection = s.ResultRows;

    for (int g = 0; g <= dataRowsCollection.Count; g++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= dataRowsCollection[g].ItemArray.Count(); i++)
        {
            var dataRows = dataRowsCollection[i].ItemArray;
            var Title = dataRows[0].ToString();
            var Url = dataRows[4].ToString();
            var TemplateId = dataRows[6].ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

Can I do this in LINQ or should I keep it like this? I can't figure out how it would look like with LINQ since its the array objects I'm working with.

Note: I will later on map `Title`, `Url` and `TemplateId` to my model class properties.

Comment: What are you trying to do with these values? This code doesn't do anything with the values it creates in the inner most for loop.

Comment: I will map the data I take out to my model class I have not implemented it yet. edited the question

Comment: Is there a reason for using LINQ?

Comment: @Obsivus Then you should include that code in the question, because: 1. It can change the answer. 2. Code Review is about reviewing real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general review of the existing code: This block does not make much sense to me:

> ```
> for (int g = 0; g <= dataRowsCollection.Count; g++)
> {
>     for (int i = 0; i <= dataRowsCollection[g].ItemArray.Count(); i++)
>     {
>         var dataRows = dataRowsCollection[i].ItemArray;
>         var Title = dataRows[0].ToString();
>         var Url = dataRows[4].ToString();
>         var TemplateId = dataRows[6].ToString();
>     }
> }
> ```

Your inner loop will only ever pull data out of the first `N` entries in `dataRowsCollection` depending what the longest `ItemArray` in any of the data rows is because you are doing this: `dataRowsCollection[i].ItemArray;`.

If we assume that each data row has an `ItemArray` of length 10 then you will pull the first 10 entries out of the `dataRowsCollection` over and over again. This seems broken.

So instead of worrying about "should I use LINQ instead of a for loop" you should worry about getting your code to work first properly. First make it work - then make it better.

Answer (score 7):

Before you ask yourself "*can I do this with LINQ?*", you need to look at the body of your loop:

> ```
> var dataRows = dataRowsCollection[i].ItemArray;
> var Title = dataRows[0].ToString();
> var Url = dataRows[4].ToString();
> var TemplateId = dataRows[6].ToString();
> ```

These variables are *scoped* to the loop's body, which means your loop is essentially useless, because each iteration will re-assign a new value to a new variable that will become candidate for garbage collection as soon as the iteration finishes.

I suspect that you haven't posted the entire loop body... or that your code doesn't do what you think it does.

> *Note: I will later on map Title, Url and TemplateId to my model class properties.*

This *has* to be done *inside* the loop's body.

As it stands / as posted, there's nothing in this loop that makes it a good candidate for a more LINQ representation that would be more readable and/or easier to maintain.

LINQ stands for *Language-INtegrated Query*, which means it's useful for *querying* objects. Your loop isn't doing that - it's *iterating* objects, and then performing assignations.

To LINQify your loop, you would have to change your logic - *query* `dataRowsCollection` and *project* (`Select`) each `ItemArray` into an `IEnumerable<T>` that contains each item's `dataRows`.

And *then* you could iterate the result of that *query* to assign your model class properties.

---

**Naming**

Naming conventions make our lives easier. Respecting them makes your code easier to follow and to understand. *Local variables* should be `camelCase`, like `dataRows` is.

The other local variables you're declaring are `PascalCase`, which makes your naming inconsistent.